# Need help with drawing on a custom made view

Tags: android, view, canvas, drawing, draw

I need your experience.
Problem : I need to be able to draw thing (rect, circ,etc) on one part of a FlipperView....
My main.xml has a main linearLayout. In this LinearLayout I have a ViewFlipper with 2 linearlayouts in it. The first linearlayout has soms buttons, inputfiels,etc... the second one should have a special view in wich I can draw the things I choose in the first part.
So I have created a new view wich extends the View class so I can play with the ondraw methode. But I can not get it to work.
This is what I have so far...
MAIN.XML

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layout_main" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_width="fill_parent"        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

//BUTTONS TEXTFIELDS ETC

```
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

//an instance of my new ViewClass

```
<Vierbergen.Tim.ViewClass
android:id="@+id/draw" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

The VIEWCLASS.java

```
public class ViewClass extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
     public DrawView(Context context) {
 super(context); 
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
 }  
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
//depending on some params....
draw this, draw that...
}
```

}

and then my main activity
DRAWER.JAVA

```
public class SmsDraw extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
ViewClass vClass;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

      vClass = (ViewClass) findViewById(R.id.draw);
    }
```

// with somewhere a draw function excecuted by a button
    private void start() {
        //where can I get a canvas ? Canvas c = new Canvas();
        blablalba
        vClass.onDraw(c);
    }

So I need to be able to draw on the thing VIEWCLASS with id = draw in my main.xml...
How can I do this ? please help me with an explanation and solution and not just a solution :-)

Thanks VeeTee

Answer (score 1):

Your `onDraw` method will be called by the framework if your `View` is attached to the view hierarchy. You don't need to call it yourself.

If you're unsure about your `onDraw` code, try using the code from a sample like [DrawPoints](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/DrawPoints.html) in API Demos.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call onDraw yourself, as Matthew has said. Here's a very simple addition to your ViewClass that would allow you to draw rectangles or circles. It hasn't been tested, so proceed carefully.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
    private boolean drawRect;
    private boolean drawCircle;
    private float rect_w;
    private float rect_h;
    private int rect_color;
    private float circle_radius;
    private int circle_color;
    Paint paint;

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    public void drawRect(float w, float h, int color) {

        // define these variables privately at the top of the class
        this.drawRect = true;
        this.drawCircle = false;
        this.rect_w = w;
        this.rect_h = h;
        this.rect_color = color;
    }

    public void drawCircle(float radius, int color) {

        // define these variables privately at the top of the class
        this.drawRect = false;
        this.drawCircle = true;
        this.circle_radius = radius;
        this.circle_color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (drawRect) {
            paint.setColor(this.rect_color);
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, rect_w, rect_h, paint);
        }
        if (drawCircle) {
            paint.setColor(this.circle_color);
            canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, circle_radius, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your view Class, call it like this:

```
vClass = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.draw);
vClass.drawRect(3,4,0x334434);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem it wasn't working the first time was...

when the main activity want to setContentView(...)... it crashes....
But when I leave it out of the xml
and create it at runtime like this

viewClass = new ViewClass(this);

```
    layke = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDraw);//wich is the second part of the flipperview
    layke.addView(viewClass); // to at it to the right layout
```

it works....